# Let X,Y identically distributed & independent. Then pdf of X-Y around a value x-y, is equal to pdf of Y-X around the value x-y. Why?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The argument says that this should hold due to symmetry as X,Y are identically distributed. But I cannot understand why this happens. Any ideas?

Comment: If $(X,Y)$ is i.i.d. then $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ follow the same distribution hence $X-Y$ and $Y-X$ follow the same distribution. If $X$ and $Y$ are only identically distributed but not independent, then $X-Y$ and $Y-X$ need not follow the same distribution.

Comment: -If X,Y are independent, then (X-Y) and (Y-X) are also independent?

Comment: ?? Of course not. But why do you ask?

Comment: Can you please provide some proof for the first statement i.e. that X-Y and (Y-X) follow the same distribution?

Comment: This is because X-Y=u(X,Y) and Y-X=u(Y,X) for the same function u and because (X,Y) and (Y,X) follow the same distribution and because, for every function u and random variable Z, the distribution of u(Z) only depends on the distribution of Z.

Comment: If X,Y are identically distributed and not independent, you said that X-Y and Y-X need not be identically distributed. Why would we need independence for them to follow the same distribution?

Comment: Because there is no way to prove that X-Y and Y-X are identically distributed assuming only that X and Y are identically distributed (and because the result actually does not hold).

Comment: Thank you. Is there any mathematical proof for the initial statement ? Also the statement ''The pdf of variable Y around the value Y= - y , is equal to pdf of -Y, around -Y = y. When does this hold?''

Comment: Under the more acceptable formulation: "Let $Y$ with PDF $f_Y$ then $Z=-Y$ has PDF $f_Z$ such that $f_Z(z)=f_Y(-z)$ for every $z$", then yes this is correct (and direct from the definitions, I should add).

Comment: Which initial statement? If this is a statement in one of my comments then yes there is.

Comment: ((Starting to delete your comments? This is unpleasant.))

Comment: The comment was added in the directly previous one - so the question still appears above your answer. Thank you. 

I was curious about the mathematical proof for ''Let X,Y identically distributed & independent. Then pdf of X-Y around a value x-y, is equal to pdf of Y-X around the value x-y''.

Comment: ?? Surely you noted that my **first** comment **proves** exactly that, by a succession of precise, elementary, steps?

Comment: Would you agree that Y and -Y are not identically distributed? 

because for example the pdf of Y in the interval [0,1] is equal to 1 , and the pdf of -Y is again equal to 1, but in the interval [-1,0].

Comment: "Would you agree that Y and -Y are not identically distributed?" 1. Yes. 2. How is this related to your question? 3. Please stop misusing the site. Please be reminded that askers are supposed to write complete, specific, questions from the start, not to engage in endless comment exchanges.

Comment: Once I find a complete mathematical answer to the question, I will place it here. Thank you for your time and valuable input.

Comment: Once again (and for the last time), my first comment contains "a complete mathematical answer to the question". But if you continue to pretend otherwise, no problem...

Comment: Again, thank you for your time and useful inputs. A previous comment states '' Because there is no way to prove that X-Y and Y-X are identically distributed assuming only that X and Y are identically distributed ''. This comment must be shown mathematically and I intend to check it a bit further and update here.

Comment: And at the same time, you add the independence hypothesis to the title? Making that the question is fully answered? O well.

Comment: Generally your answers provided great insight and real assistance in the process of my understanding of the issue. I am grateful for your time and constant responses. I will need to work a bit more on the question for a better understanding.